# Django - aggregation with get_FOO_display

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

Consider the following:

```
status = queryset.values('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))
```

where `status` field is a `CharField` with `choices`. This will result in a list of dictionaries with `status` DB value along with its count.

Is there a way to aggregate `status` and show its display value instead? I have looked up the code of `_get_FIELD_display` which I probably can emulate, but it feels a tad hackish to repeat the framework's internal code.

Comment: Can you update your question with a input -> expected output example?

Comment: @Germano isn't the question clear enough? `status` -> `status` aggregated with its display value

Comment: My bad, I missed that status has choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without hacking a SQL, you may not achieve this in DB level easily. But, since `get_FOO_display` operates on `Model` level, you don't even have to hack `_get_FIELD_display` or lookup in choices manually (If the following method does not cost your server too much):

```
YourModel(status=status).get_status_display()
```

Thus

```
for s in queryset.values('status').annotate(count=Count('status')):
    print(queryset.model(status=s['status']).get_status_display())
```

Comment: `get_FOO_display` is added dynamically, it's not available like you put it, unless you meant something else. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `django.contrib.admin.util.display_for_field` function. You have to find the field object:

```
field = queryset.model._meta.get_field('status')
```

Then you can use it as:

```
display_for_field(status, field)
```

Or, in your case:

```
{ unicode(display_for_field(t['status'], field)): t['count']
    for t in queryset.values('taxonomy').annotate(count=models.Count('taxonomy'))}
```

Comment: What is taxonomy indicating here? Why doesn't status belong in the values args, given that it is the column he is trying to group by? I'm interested in accomplishing this without an extra for loop.